# Trouble with python3 web.py

Tags: python, web.py

I'm taking an online class in python and trying to build a website using web.py. I am running `python 3.6.1` on a Windows 10 machine. I was able to install web.py manually as required and verify that it is imported correctly. I have tried both the "python3" and "p3" branches of web.py from github and both result in the same problem.

I have what I believe to be a simple set of three pages defined as seen in the "urls" statement below. When I run the code then go to my browser and enter `http://localhost:8080/`, I expect to see the Home page. However, I get random results, as if the `web.application()` call is randomly picking two of the elements in urls. I get any of the following results:

```
 404 - Not found
 500 - Key Error: '/register'
 500 - Key Error: '/postregistration'
 200 - Returns the Home page
 200 - Returns the Registration page
 200 - Returns the PostRegistration page
```

Note that I never entered `http://localhost:8080/register` or `/postregistration`, yet sometimes the browser would render those pages as if I did.

I can't make sense out of what it is doing and I thought I was following the instructor's examples line for line. Any thoughts?

```
import web
from Models import RegisterModel

urls = {
    '/', 'Home',
    '/register', 'Register',
    '/postregistration', 'PostRegistration'
}

render = web.template.render("Views/Templates", base="MainLayout")
app = web.application(urls, globals())

#Classes/Routes

class Home:
    def GET(self):
        return render.Home()

class Register:
    def GET(self):
        return render.Register()

class PostRegistration:
    def POST(self):
        data = web.input()

        reg_model = RegisterModel.RegisterModel()
        reg_model.insert_user(data)
        return data.username

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `urls` variable is a `set`. It should be a `tuple`. Change your code from this:

```
urls = {
    '/', 'Home',
    '/register', 'Register',
    '/postregistration', 'PostRegistration'
}
```

To this:

```
urls = (
    '/', 'Home',
    '/register', 'Register',
    '/postregistration', 'PostRegistration'
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That took care of my problem.

Comment: @DaCone If the answer solved the issue, it is a good practice to accept it.